# What's the best way to escape user input for Regular Expressions in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, escaping

I'd like to take user input, denoted as `$dangerous_string`, and use it as part of a RegEx in a MySQL query.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I want to use the user's string as a literal -- if it contains any characters that mean something in MySQL RegEx, those characters should not actually affect my Regular Expression.

```
$dangerous_string = $_GET["string"];
//do something here
$dangerous_string = what_goes_here($dangerous_string);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE search_column REGEX '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string("[[:<:]]$dangerous_string") . "'";

//etc....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no native way of escaping for MySQL regex.  You can do it in PHP with preg_quote (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) which would probably do the job for you, but is obviously not designed for the purpose.

My preferred way if I were in your situation would be to construct a regex whitelist in PHP that you can then apply to your dangerous string:

```
$safeString = preg_replace('/[^\w]/','',$dangerousString);
```

This removes any non-word characters (i.e. anything except A-Za-z0-9_) from your string.

NB I believe the other answers given will not remove/escape regex special characters, which I believe is your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

## Use `preg_quote` and replace `&` manually

[`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) takes a string and escapes special characters with a backslash. It is meant for PHP regexes, not MySQL regexes, and it does not escape `&`, which is needed for MySQL. So we only need to modify it like so:

```
function escape_regex_for_mysql($dangerous_string) {
    return preg_replace('/&/', '\\&', preg_quote($dangerous_string));
}
```

Note that you should still use prepared statements (or `$mysqli->real_escape_string`) on top, like this:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM table WHERE search_column REGEXP %s',
    '[[:<:]]' . escape_regex_for_mysql($dangerous_string)
);
```

## Rationale:

Let's look at MySQL's documentation to see which characters will need to be escaped. [The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) says:

> MySQL >= 8.0.4 implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU), which provides full Unicode support and is multibyte safe.

So let's look at [the documentation for the ICU project](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp):

> \ (outside of sets) Quotes the following character. Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are * ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ .
>
> \ (inside sets) Quotes the following character. Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are [ ] \ Characters that may need to be quoted, depending on the context are - &

So the list of special characters that need to be escaped are `* ? + [ ] ( ) { } ^ $ \ . - &`. `preg_quote` escapes all of these except `&`. It also escapes some characters unnecessarily, but MySQL will handle that as expected.

Alternatively, you can add `&` as a second parameter to `preg_quote` for it to be escaped, e.g. `preg_quote('AT&T', '&')`

Comment: it seems that reg exps have to use double slashes not single slashes to work properly. str_replace('\\', '\\\\', preg_replace('/&/', '\\&', preg_quote($dangerous_string)))

Comment: @luky The double slashes in your example are there because you are using string literals. If you were to run `echo '\\`;` or `echo '\\&'` you would only see only one backslash. The function `echo` in that example is only receiving one backslash. You need to escape things properly when using string literals, and in addition you need to use `preg_quote` to escape for uses like the one in this question.

Comment: i am not using any literals i am using the function preg_quote and variable, mysql itself needs the double slashes i believe.

Answer (score -2):

You need to ensure that quotes and ticks are properly handled
before passing to the database.  The best method for this is:

```
   mysql_real_escape_string  ([php doc][1])
```

This method is available in both PHP, and C++ mysql client libraries.

This should ensure any 'dangerous_string' is no longer dangerous 
and can be used within a quoted string used by RegEx.

Comment: Does do nothing for REGEXP interpretation, which was the question.