# PHP function to escape MySQL regexp syntax

Tags: php, mysql, regex, escaping

I'm looking for something similar to preg_quote, but for the MySQL regexp syntax.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to escape user input for Regular Expressions in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782379/whats-the-best-way-to-escape-user-input-for-regular-expressions-in-mysql)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL regexps are the ‘extended’ POSIX variant (ERE), available in PHP as the deprecated `ereg_` functions.

Unfortunately there is no `ereg_quote` in PHP, however PCRE's special characters are a superset of ERE's special characters, and backslash-escaping a non-special punctuation character doesn't harm it, so you *can* get away with using `preg_quote` safely.

(Naturally you will need parameterised queries or `mysql_real_escape_string` *after* that quoting, to stop the backslashes being misinterpreted as MySQL's non-ANSI-standard string literal escapes.)

Comment: Slight caveat: the null control character. `preg_quote` escapes it to `\000`, which is a format MySQL doesn't recognise. But then MySQL's regex engine can't cope with null characters anyway, it takes them as terminators.

Comment: I had to use str_replace('?', '\\?', preg_quote()), since preg_quote() could produce ? when it doesen't know spectial UTF8 characters. And ? needs to be escaped in the regexp.

Comment: A problem! `mysql_real_escape_string` will escape backslash characters. This feature causes all backslashes to be escaped again (if you use `mysql_real_escape_string` after quoting)!

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili yes, you should only `mysql_real_escape_string` if you are injecting the regex into a SQL query string literal, in which case you do actually need the extra backslashes. Normally, it would be better to use parameterised queries and avoid the need for extra escaping.

Comment: And to complete the answer: to use parameterized REGEXP you can use `CONCAT` like this: `WHERE field REGEXP CONCAT('regexp part 1', ?, 'regexp part 2')` and bind `preg_quote($field)` to `?` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, PHP's `preg_quote()` messes up MySQL REGEXP by escaping a colon sign (:)  which MySQL's REGEXP does not understand

Comment: So is the best approach to preg_quote then replace all escaped colons with unescaped colons?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Try it with MySQL: `$statement = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT %s REGEXP %s", 'hello:you', 'hello\\:you' )`

Answer (score 1):

There's no native MySQL function for that. You might just need to use `preg_quote` before passing the regular expression to the MySQL query.

Comment: `preg_quote` does not escape `&` which is needed for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (PHP)

```
    $tags="test'*\\\r blue";
    $tags=mysql_real_escape_string($tags);
    $tags=preg_replace('/([.*?+\[\]{}^$|(\)])/','\\\\\1',$tags);
    $tags=preg_replace('/(\\\[.*?+\[\]{}^$|(\)\\\])/','\\\\\1',$tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank [@bobince's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024382/5318303). But it has a problem if you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` after quoting, that I mentioned it in a comment.

Actually `preg_quote` and `mysql_real_escape_string` have overlap and it makes this problem! **`mysql_real_escape_string` must not escape `\` in this case**. So I suggest:

```
function regexpEscape(/*string*/ $input) { // Uncomment `string` for PHP 7.0+
    return addcslashes(preg_quote($input), "\0'\"\n\r\x1A"); // charlist = All characters that escape by real_escape_string except backslash
}
```

(For `charlist` see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

I know this is not an ideal way, but couldn't find a better way.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with escaping the regex, and then escaping using `mysql_real_escape_string`