# Convert standard simplified pattern ( * ? ) to the LIKE pattern ( % _ )

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I would like to know if there is a better way than :

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('p%a_t*er?', '\\', '\\\\'), '%', '\%'), '_', '\_'), '*', '%'), '?', '_')
```

To transform standard search patterns `*` and `?` to the LIKE equivalents `%` and `_` in MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a shorter method to perform multiple-character replacements directly in MySQL. There are alternatives such as User-Defined-Functions (UDFs), but I'm doubtful that any would be beneficial to your exact purpose.

My suggestion would be to perform the text replacement prior-to querying the database, if acceptable.

In PHP, this could be done with:

```
$searchQuery = $_GET['q'];
$searchQuery = str_replace(array('*', '?'), array('%', '_'), $searchQuery);
// perform your query as normal
```

In ASP, you could try:

```
string searchQuery = Request.QueryString["q"];
searchQuery = searchQuery.Replace("*", "%").Replace("?", "_");
// perform your query as normal
```

Though, both method aren't super-short, they do make it a little easier to read and also won't add any time to your db-query. Also, doing the replacement prior to the query will allow you to replace before the string is sanitized so you won't need to replace the `\` as you do in your existing query - which saves you one replacement!

Comment: In fact, the pattern is a value that could be anything alreay in MySQL format. To make it simple, this pattern could be CONCAT(X) with X being anything possible in MySQL (a mix of udf calls and strings and fields). So I think you're the most closer to a good solution with UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `like` you can use [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) of Mysql like this:

```
select * from my_table where col_name regexp 'p%a_t*er?';
```

While using regexp there is no need to do all those replacements to make your string `like` friendly.

Comment: But it may be special regexp chars (`$`, `^`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)` etc.) in my simplified pattern, i still need to inhibit them. And i can't ask my customer to learn regexp :-)

Comment: If you're using PHP then you can do is to quote the text using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024188/php-function-to-escape-mysql-regexp-syntax

Comment: but this will also quote my * and ?, so I will need to unquote those chars. And isn't `.*` the correct regexp pattern to handle `*` simplified one?