# Finding MySQL records that contain an exact string

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm working on a project that needs to look for records that contain an exact string, or the same string as part of an exact format. In other words, if the string is "hello world", there might be say... 10 records in the database that have this field value, but the field might be one of the following:

```
"1. hello world"
"1 hello world"
"hello world"
"hello world (xyz)"
"1. hello world (xyz)"
"1 hello world (zyx)"
```

The string "hello world" could be anything but the prefix always either starts with a number or doesn't exist, and the suffix always either ends in a bracket or doesn't exist.

I thought I'd cracked it with the following regex, but this isn't returning any records:

```
WHERE fieldname REGEXP '^([0-9]+.*)?[[:<:]]hello world[[:>:]](.*\))?$'
```

Additionally, I've never used [[:<:]] [[:>:]] before and assuming this is the way to go, I'm not sure how to escape the text between since this will be PHP generated? The documentation says to double-up the escaping backslashes so I'm guessing mysql_real_escape_string isn't enough...?

Any advice would, as usual, be much appreciated.

Comment: What about `LIKE '%hello world%'`? See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: A basic LIKE wouldn't be enough unfortunately, as I need to exclude records that don't follow this format. For example "different hello world (xyz)" or "1. hello world two"

Comment: Could try [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59f2c9/11/0) `'^([0-9].*)?[[:<:]]hello world($|[[:>:]].+[)]$)'`

Comment: Ohhh, that seems to work! Frustratingly this approach seems to be slower than combining a bunch of LIKE's, but as an answer to my question you've nailed it, thanks. Post as an answer please and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the last part `[[:>:]](.*\))?$` to an alternation as a workaround.

```
^([0-9].*)?[[:<:]]hello world($|[[:>:]].+[)]$)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59f2c9/11/0)

If unsure regarding escaping, try to put the special characters into a character class `[)]` and [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4024188/5527985) for escaping the dynamic part of the string.

Comment: Works exactly as I was expecting, thanks. Annoyingly a single REGEXP appears to be about 4 times slower than multiple LIKE's though, after all that! http://pastebin.com/dcQTQENp

Comment: @Ric you could additonally try to switch the first part `^([0-9].*)?[[:<:]]` to `(^|^[0-9].*[[:<:]])` Didn't test if this would utilize an index (use EXPLAIN). Else yes - probably you'd need to split into several queries for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WHERE fieldname LIKE '%hello world%'
```

You can read more about "LIKE" [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Comment: A basic LIKE wouldn't be enough unfortunately, as I need to exclude records that don't follow this format. For example "different hello world (xyz)" or "1. hello world two"

Comment: So what do you want exactly?

Comment: This is what does work, but it's too slow, even with indexes. I'm hoping to replace with a signle regex search.. http://pastebin.com/dcQTQENp