# Use SQL REGEXP (mariadb) for filter in where with special characters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, mysql-regexp

##### mariadb version `10.4`

```
$query->where('column', 'REGEXP', '[[:<:]]'.$string.'[[:>:]]');
```

This query provides a search with whole words only and that's working fine without special characters.

#### Example

###### Searching row:

```
foo (bar baz)
```

###### Filter:

```
$string = "(bar";
$query->where('column', 'REGEXP', '[[:<:]]'.$string.'[[:>:]]');
```

###### Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'missing )
```

Now I tried with `addcslashes` and `preg_quote`. I succeed to escape `(` character with `preg_quote` but the filter won't work for that string because the filter works with whole words.

Any suggestion for better filtering by the whole word will be also appreciated.

### One more example

###### Searching row:

```
foo(bar baz
```

###### Filter:

```
$filter = 'foo(bar';
$query->where('column', 'REGEXP', '[[:<:]]'.$string.'[[:>:]]');
```

If `(` will be escaped the search will not work

Comment: Does `whereRaw()` work?

Comment: Same result. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627403/7451109

Comment: Does `'[[:<:]]\\\\(bar[[:>:]]'` work?

Comment: Same result @Olivier

Comment: This may be important:  What version of MySQL/MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of punctuation marks that have special meaning in `REGEXP` strings.  `(` is just one of many.

If the goal is the search for the 4 characters `(bar` with a trailing "word boundary", then one of these may work -- *depending* on the version of MySQL/MariaDB *and* what escaping is needed to get from your app to the server:

```
\(bar[[:>:]]
\\(bar[[:>:]]
\\\\(bar[[:>:]]
[(]bar[[:>:]]

\(bar\b
\\(bar\\b
\\\\(bar\\\\b
[(]bar\b
[(]bar\\b
[(]bar\\\\b
```

In any case *your app* must do some escaping.  Given that, it *may* be better to *remove* punctuation:

```
[[:<:]]bar[[:>:]]
\bbar\b
\\bbar\\b
\\\\bbar\\\\b
```

Consider also using `LIKE "(bar"`

Consider also using a `FULLTEXT` index

```
MATCH(col) AGAINST("bar" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

For maximal performance, this may be best (with a FULLTEXT index):

```
MATCH(col) AGAINST("bar" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND col LIKE "(bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `$string = '\(bar';`

You can always check your regex pattern here : https://regex101.com/

Comment: I did it with `preg_quote` and `addcslashes`. But that isn't what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the [ICU](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) regex library that you're using considers brackets to be special, and requires **double** slash escaping. Using `add_slashes()` is not useful because it would add slashes where required by other libraries that aren't ICU's, and it might give you a string that is not appropriate for it (e.g. it wouldn't escape round brackets).

You might have better luck with `escapeshellcmd()` due to the fact that the round and square brackets are, by chance, both shell metacharacters, but so are the dollar sign and the hash sign and this might come and bite you in the back later.

The simpler solution would be to manually replace the four characters you need (actually *three*, ( ) [, but for completeness' sake...).

```
$string = preg_replace(
    '#([(\\[\\])])#', 
    '\\\\\\\\\1', // Hilarious, isn't it?
    $string
);

$query->where('column', 'REGEXP', '[[:<:]]'.$string.'[[:>:]]');
```